# How to move a shape across a ppt slide in a slideshow?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I want to display a slide that shows a graphic moving from one part of the slide to another. I actually want to animate a number of objects doing this. Animation in powerpoint doesn't appear to let me do this.

The best solution I have is to fade out an object in one location and have it fade in in a different location.

Not what I want but maybe it will have to do.  Unless someone can help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Which version of PowerPoint? If 2010, have you tried selecting the shape, clicking the Animations tab and expanding the options so that you can then select the Motion Path type you want?

[image: PPT 2010 Animation]

Answer (score 0):

Powerpoint 15.2 on my mac has "Morph" Transition. All you have to do is

1. Duplicate the slide
2. Set transition to Morph
3. Move the objects to new location and if require resize it.

Now, run slide show. Object automatically moves to new location while also resizing it.